# workin with images and crud in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, crud

Is there anyone who knows how to upload when working with CRUD in mvc asp.net so that my image will be uploaded inside my header, either in its own div or a specific div inside the header, right now i can upload the pictures inside the content in body but i dont know how to upload it to my logoelement in header.

here is the code so you can see where i want it to be displayed
@model IEnumerable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    </head>
<body>
    <header>
           <div id="float-logo"><img src="@Model.PicUrl" alt="" /></div>
           <div id="title"><p class="site-title">@Html.Action("SiteInfo", "Home")</p></div>
            <div class="float-login">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
            </div>
                <nav id="MainNav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Rapporter", "Index", "Report")</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="Layout">
        <nav id="SideNav"></nav>
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="Content">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

this is a part of the controller which creates it:

```
public class PictureController : Controller
{
    private ItbTidCmsEntities db = new ItbTidCmsEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Picture/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var pictures = db.Pictures.Include("Category");
        return View(pictures.ToList());
    }
    public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {

        ViewBag.CatID = id;
        var category = db.Categories.First(c => c.CatID == id.Value);
        ViewBag.CatName = category.CatName;

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Picture/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Picture picture)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pictures.AddObject(picture);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Content", "Admin", new { id = picture.CatID });
        }

        ViewBag.CatID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CatID", "CatName", picture.CatID);
        return View(picture);
    }
```

admin model:

```
namespace ItbTid.Models
{
    public class Admin
    {
        public List<Category> category { get; set; }
        public List<Text> text { get; set; }
        public List<Picture> picture { get; set; }
        public List<Video> video { get; set; }
        public List<Link> link { get; set; }
    }
}
```

timeentrylistmodel:

```
namespace ItbTid.Models
{
  public class TimeEntryListModel
  {
    public IEnumerable<TimeEntry> TimeEntries { get; set; }
    public SelectList Customers { get; set; }
    public long? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
   }

  //Vi la till denna
  public class RegTimeModel
  {
      public TimeEntryListModel TimeEntryListModel { get; set; }
      public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<Customer> customerlist { get; set; }
  }
}
```

This is a piece of the code from database css_db.designer.cs:

```
public partial class Picture : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new Picture object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="picID">Initial value of the PicID property.</param>
    /// <param name="picUrl">Initial value of the PicUrl property.</param>
    /// <param name="picAltText">Initial value of the PicAltText property.</param>
    public static Picture CreatePicture(global::System.Int64 picID, global::System.String picUrl, global::System.String picAltText)
    {
        Picture picture = new Picture();
        picture.PicID = picID;
        picture.PicUrl = picUrl;
        picture.PicAltText = picAltText;
        return picture;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int64 PicID
    {
        get
        {
            return _PicID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_PicID != value)
            {
                OnPicIDChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("PicID");
                _PicID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("PicID");
                OnPicIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int64 _PicID;
    partial void OnPicIDChanging(global::System.Int64 value);
    partial void OnPicIDChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String PicTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return _PicTitle;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPicTitleChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("PicTitle");
            _PicTitle = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("PicTitle");
            OnPicTitleChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _PicTitle;
    partial void OnPicTitleChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnPicTitleChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String PicUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _PicUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPicUrlChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("PicUrl");
            _PicUrl = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("PicUrl");
            OnPicUrlChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _PicUrl;
    partial void OnPicUrlChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnPicUrlChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String PicAltText
    {
        get
        {
            return _PicAltText;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPicAltTextChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("PicAltText");
            _PicAltText = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("PicAltText");
            OnPicAltTextChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _PicAltText;
    partial void OnPicAltTextChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnPicAltTextChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String PicDesc
    {
        get
        {
            return _PicDesc;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPicDescChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("PicDesc");
            _PicDesc = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("PicDesc");
            OnPicDescChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _PicDesc;
    partial void OnPicDescChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnPicDescChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public Nullable<global::System.Int64> PicPrio
    {
        get
        {
            return _PicPrio;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPicPrioChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("PicPrio");
            _PicPrio = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("PicPrio");
            OnPicPrioChanged();
        }
    }
    private Nullable<global::System.Int64> _PicPrio;
    partial void OnPicPrioChanging(Nullable<global::System.Int64> value);
    partial void OnPicPrioChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public Nullable<global::System.Int64> CatID
    {
        get
        {
            return _CatID;
        }
        set
        {
            OnCatIDChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("CatID");
            _CatID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("CatID");
            OnCatIDChanged();
        }
    }
    private Nullable<global::System.Int64> _CatID;
    partial void OnCatIDChanging(Nullable<global::System.Int64> value);
    partial void OnCatIDChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Byte[] PicDateCreated
    {
        get
        {
            return StructuralObject.GetValidValue(_PicDateCreated);
        }
        set
        {
            OnPicDateCreatedChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("PicDateCreated");
            _PicDateCreated = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("PicDateCreated");
            OnPicDateCreatedChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Byte[] _PicDateCreated;
    partial void OnPicDateCreatedChanging(global::System.Byte[] value);
    partial void OnPicDateCreatedChanged();

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("ItbTidCmsModel", "FK_Pictures_Categories", "Categories")]
    public Category Category
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Category>("ItbTidCmsModel.FK_Pictures_Categories", "Categories").Value;
        }
        set
        {
            ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Category>("ItbTidCmsModel.FK_Pictures_Categories", "Categories").Value = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public EntityReference<Category> CategoryReference
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Category>("ItbTidCmsModel.FK_Pictures_Categories", "Categories");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedReference<Category>("ItbTidCmsModel.FK_Pictures_Categories", "Categories", value);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it to be displayed in the left-top of the page. Just put your image in `<div id="title">`.

Comment: if i put my url image in div id float-logo then im getting an error for Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'ItbTid.Models.TimeEntryListModel' does not contain a definition for 'PicUrl'

Comment: can you paste your TimeEntryListModel in your Model class, too

Comment: you're calling TimeEntryListModel.PicUrl with what you're doing now, but you don't have a PicUrl attribute in that model. how do you keep PicUrl? i mean where is it?

Comment: it should be calling from ItdTid.Models.Category, the code is from my colleges so i dont really understand how they have done it but ive puzzled up the most pieces

Comment: ive updated with another piece of code from css_db.designer.cs(sql database)

Comment: please delete all your code other than view. try pasting this on top of your view: @model IEnumerable<ItdTid.Models.Picture>

Comment: do u mean in my shared layout view?

Comment: let me know for further progress when you can.

Comment: i forgot to say/edit that this is the code that is calling the images <div id="float-logo"><img src="@Model.PicUrl" alt="" /></div> this code is now placed in shared layout, before it was in a seperated partailview that was connected to the renderbody section. I just remembered on the way that i know a different soution for it which is kinda cheat when it can be done in a properly way but i can solve it with z-index

Comment: i'm confused, did you paste the line i recommended to the top of the layout view, which is in the Shared directory? did that work? cheat? you mean workaround i guess, you might need to take a look at webViewExtensions about that.

Comment: i tried with ur code but it still didnt work, one thing that i dont understand is why i cant use @models.pickurl in img src while this works on the other projekt, all the files are in the right place, and i can find my others tables column but not do i find any in my picture table

Comment: just found out that i forgot to copy a folder to the projekt, now i can find my pickurl, but when i place <div id="float-logo"><img src="@Model.PickUrl" alt=""/></div> inside header in shared layout this is what i get:Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'ItbTid.Models.ReportModel' does not contain a definition for 'PickUrl', and whats underline with red is @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

Comment: you're working on a view page that has 'ItbTid.Models.ReportModel' as it's model, it's defined at the top of that view page. try changing it to 'ItbTid.Models.Picture'.

Comment: ive updated so u can se what i have on the top, and im using the code that u linked on top of the head and the message that im getting is :Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ItbTid.Models.Picture>' does not contain a definition for 'PickUrl' and no extension method 'PickUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ItbTid.Models.Picture>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: IEnumerable represents a List of objects, so you need to go through pictures within a foreach block. in your controller you wrote "return View(pictures.ToList());". if you need only one picture, you should write "return View(picture);", picture is a Picture object here. after that you should change the view's top line to "@model ItdTid.Models.Picture"

Comment: sorry, but from here i think i cannot help you more, i got really tired :) i need to see the project myself to help you. your problem isn't at one place, there are many changes you should make. i suggest going through some tutorials. by then, please minimize the code in your project and just leave the most relevant parts. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the picture URL in this action

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Picture picture)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pictures.AddObject(picture);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Content", "Admin", new { id = picture.CatID });
        }

        ViewBag.CatID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CatID", "CatName", picture.CatID);
        return View(picture);
//Return picture URL here
    }
```